# PHP проверка столбцов на значения больше нуля

Tags: php

Есть функция которая проверяет строки выбранных столбов на значения больше нуля, сделано это для того, чтобы пользователю было понятно в каком столбце проблема(в каком столбце у строк нули).
Вот сама функция, ну это не совсем то, что надо. Сейчас объясню.

```
function check_zeros($p_csv)
{
    $check = '';
    foreach ($p_csv as $row) {
        if ($row[3] != 0 && $row[5] != 0) {
            $check = '1';
            break;
        }
        if ($row[3] == 0 && $row[5] == 0) {
            $check = '2';
            break;
        }
        if ($row[3] == 0) {
            $check = '3';
            break;
        }
        if ($row[5] == 0) {
            $check = '4';
            break;
        }
    }
    return $check;
}
```

Т.е. первый If проверяет если есть значение больше нуля для всех строк столбцов, тогда прерываем перебор массива, возвращаем '1'.
Если он не находит у всех строк в обоих столбцах значения больше нуля, делаем второй if который проверит строку обоих столбцов, на значения равным 0, если в обоих столбцах 0, тогда возвращаем 2, прерываем перебор массива.
Третий if проверяет строку столбца на значение равным нулю, возвращает 3 если значение строки для выбранного столбца равно 0. Точно так же и для 4го if.
**Проблема в том, что с 2го по 4ый if он проверяет только первую строку выбранных столбцов, а надо чтобы он проверял все строки на значения больше нуля.
Т.Е. могут приходить данные 0, 0, 1 для первого столбца(через запятую, это значит новая строка) и 0, 0, 1 для второго.
У меня лишь проверит что в первом столбце первая строка 0, и выведет ошибку, что в первом столбце все нули, так и не дойдя до 3 строки где указано 1.**

И далее у меня есть другая функция, в которой я вызываю функцию check_zeros таким образом

```
if(check_zeros($csv) == '2')
{
    $error_string = "Все значения для обоих столбцов равны 0";
    $error = true;
    return;
}
if(check_zeros($csv) == '3')
{
    $error_string = "Все значения для 3го столбца равны 0";
    $error = true;
    return;
}
if(check_zeros($csv) == '4')
{
    $error_string = "все значения для 5го столбца равны 0";
    $error = true;
    return;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу реализовать, чтобы он все строки проверял и четко выводил ошибку, указывая пользователю в каком столбце у него проблема.
Надеюсь я смог правильно донести мысль, и вы меня поймете, так же прошу прощения за орфографию. Чукча не писатель.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: приложите вывод команды var_export($p_csv);

Comment: Вы слишком углубились в свою логику, в ваши проблемы тут не все будут вникать. Опишите вопрос проще: что на входе, что должно быть на выходе, приведите примеры и мы вам покажем решение.

Comment: @Manitikyl Постараюсь объяснить максимально кратко и ясно. Есть 2 столбца куда передаются данные. Для примера в 1ый столбец приходят данные 0,0,1. Во второй столбец приходят данные 0,0,0.(всего тут 3 строки, а могут приходить тысячи). Чтобы сразу знать в каком столбце проблема и не перебирать файл с которого приходят эти данные в ручную, мне необходима проверка. В каком из столбцов все данные нули, это может быть в 1ом столбце, может во 2ом, или сразу в обоих. 
Понимаете мой вопрос?

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer, вот что приходит с var_export($p_csv)
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '$GPRMC', 1 => '212805', 2 => 'A', 3 => '0', 4 => 'N', 5 => '0', 6 => 'E', 7 => '0.00', 8 => '190', 9 => '020118', 10 => '', 11 => '', ), 1 => array ( 0 => '$GPRMC', 1 => '222805', 2 => 'A', 3 => '0', 4 => 'N', 5 => '1', 6 => 'E', 7 => '0.00', 8 => '190', 9 => '020118', 10 => '', 11 => '', ), 2 => array ( 0 => '$GPRMC', 1 => '232805', 2 => 'A', 3 => '0', 4 => 'N', 5 => '0', 6 => 'E', 7 => '0.00', 8 => '190', 9 => '020118', 10 => '', 11 => '', ), )
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function check_zeros($p_csv)
{
    /**
    * Правила проверки столбцов в формате 'ошибка(код ошибки) => номера столбцов'
    */
    $rules = [
        'Все значения для обоих столбцов равны 0' => [3,5],
        'Все значения для 3го столбца равны 0' => [3],
        'Все значения для 5го столбца равны 0' => [5]
    ];

    foreach($rules as $error => $rule) { // для каждого правила 
        $zero = []; // создаем пустой массив
        foreach ($rule as $col) { // для каждого столбца
            foreach ($p_csv as $row) // перебираем строки
            if ($row[$col] === 0) { 
                $zero[] = true; // записываем в массив при нахождении нулевого элемента в столбце
            }
        }

        if (count($zero) === count($p_csv) * count($rule)) {
            return $error; // в случае, когда количество нулей для текущего правила равно количеству строк умноженному на количество проверяемых столбцов возвращаем ошибку;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$arr = [

    [1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0],

];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(check_zeros($arr));
echo '<pre>';
```

С точки зрения производительности, это неоптимальный вариант решения задачи, если количество строк будет очень большим и количество проверяемых столбцов будет расти, то следует оптимизировать код.

**UPD**

Оптимизированый вариант алгоритма:

```
function check_zeros($p_csv)
{
    $rules = [
        'Все значения для обоих столбцов равны 0' => [3,5],
        'Все значения для 3го столбца равны 0' => [3],
        'Все значения для 5го столбца равны 0' => [5]
    ];

    foreach($rules as $error => $rule) {
        foreach ($rule as $col) {
            foreach ($p_csv as $row)
            if ($row[$col] !== 0) {
                continue 3; // переходим к следующему правилу, если элемент в столбце не равен нулю
            }
        }

        return $error;

    }

    return false;
}

$arr = [

    [1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1],

];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(check_zeros($arr));
echo '<pre>';
```

**UPD2**

Пример использования в контексте вопроса:

```
if ( $error = boolval($error_string = check_zeros($p_csv)) ) {
   return;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все идеально работает. 
Можно пожалуйста описать как она отрабатывает? Не совсем понимаю. Я новичок:)

Comment: @Богдан Лисовский прокомментировал

Comment: Огромное спасибо, остался один вопрос, как обращаться к ошибке при вызове функции?
Вроде такого 
if(check_zeros($csv) == 'Все значения для обоих столбцов равны 0')
{
    $error_string = "Все значения для обоих столбцов равны 0";
    $error = true;
    return;
}

Comment: @Богдан Лисовский обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо Вам огромнейшое, кучу времени потратил на это. Все отлично отрабатывает!
Вопрос закрыт.